# Ruby partner pairing program not working?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am new to ruby and have this program that takes in a number of names and sorting them into pairs of two, and throwing the odd person in a random group. Sometimes it works perfect, sometimes it throws the extra person into an array of their own, and im not sure why. I know there is a cleaner way to do this but Im just trying to understand how the code works. For example it should return "Apple" "Banana" "Orange" as ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple"] and will most of the time, but sometimes it give me ["Banana","Orange",] ["Apple"] Any advice?

```
def randomArray

  classNames = []
  puts "Please enter a list of names to sort"
  while true
    input = gets.chomp
    break if input.empty?
    classNames << input
  end
  classRandom = classNames.shuffle
  splitNames = classRandom.each_slice(2).to_a

  arrayPos = 0
  splitNames.length.times do

    if splitNames[arrayPos].length == 2
      arrayPos+=1   
    else splitNames[arrayPos].length == 1
      splitNames.sample << splitNames[arrayPos].pop
      arrayPos+=1
    end 
  end

  x = 0
  splitNames.length.times do
    break if splitNames[x].empty?
    puts "Group number #{x+1} is #{splitNames[x]}"
    x+=1
  end
end

randomArray
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this: `splitNames.sample << splitNames[arrayPos].pop`

`sample` can return *any* element of the array, *including* the element that has the odd person you're trying to assign! So if it samples that person, it removes them from their group of 1 and then adds them right back in.

To fix it, take advantage of the fact that either all groups will be pairs, or the last group will have a single person. Don't iterate over the array, just check `splitNames[-1]`. If they are alone, add them to `splitNames[0...-1].sample`.

Comment: Doh! Thank you very much!